# nagios core v4, please help me add more service checks for a single host

Tags: nagios

I am having difficulties understanding the documentation and would appreciate clarification.

I have NRPE and nagios plugins installed from source on both the nagios server and its clients.

Can somebody provide additional service checks that I can add to this 'database' servers, such as check_disk check_users check_load etc....

I am having difficulty with the syntax:

```
define host {

        use                          linux-server

        host_name                    database

        alias                        database

        address                      database

        register                     1

}

define service{

      host_name                       database

      service_description             PING

      check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%

      max_check_attempts              2

      check_interval                  2

      retry_interval                  2

      check_period                    24x7

      check_freshness                 1

      contact_groups                  admins

      notification_interval           2

      notification_period             24x7

      notifications_enabled           1

      register                        1

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new check like `check_disk` for your host `database` you have to define a new service and use `check_nrpe` as command and the name of your check as option (could be in `advanced_services.cfg`)

example:

`define service {
                service_description                   Diskspace
                max_check_attempts                    4
                check_interval                        10
                retry_interval                        5
                first_notification_delay              2
                notification_interval                 45
                active_checks_enabled                 1
                passive_checks_enabled                1
                notifications_enabled                 1
                check_command                         check_nrpe!check_disk
                check_period                          24x7
                notification_period                   24x7
                host_name                             database
                contact_groups                        admins
                use                                   generic-service
}`

You must ensure that "check_disk" is defined in your NRPE-client config (don't forget to reload/restart NRPE on your client after editing your conf).

Comment: You can omit anything that's already defined in the generic-service template (probably everything except `service_description`, `host_name`, `check_command`, and `use`)